# SimpleCursorAdapter вставка данных из БД в TextView

Tags: java, android

Подскажите, в нужную `TextView` вставляется первая подходящая запись из БД, при свайпе должна вставляться следующая запись в `TextView` в новом айтеме, но по факту дублируется первая.

Испльзую эту либу https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards

```
public class CardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SimpleCursorAdapter simpleCursorAdapter;
    Cursor cursor;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    DBHelper dbHelper;
    String[] selectionArgs = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_card);

         SwipeFlingAdapterView flingContainer = (SwipeFlingAdapterView) findViewById(R.id.frame);
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        Intent intent1 = getIntent();
        selectionArgs = intent1.getStringArrayExtra("selection_args");
        //String[] selectionArgs = {"food"};
        String [] colForQuery  = new String[] {"_id","col_rus"};

        cursor = db.query("my_table",colForQuery,"col_category =?",selectionArgs,null,null,null);

        String[] stringFrom = new String[]{DBHelper.COL_RUS} ;
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.helloText};

        simpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.item,cursor,stringFrom,to);

        flingContainer.setAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);

        flingContainer.setFlingListener(new SwipeFlingAdapterView.onFlingListener() {

            @Override
            public void removeFirstObjectInAdapter() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onLeftCardExit(Object dataObject) {

                Toast.makeText(CardActivity.this, "Left!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onRightCardExit(Object dataObject) {
                Toast.makeText(CardActivity.this, "Right!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdapterAboutToEmpty(int itemsInAdapter) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(float v) {

            }
        });

        flingContainer.setOnItemClickListener(new SwipeFlingAdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClicked(int itemPosition, Object dataObject) {
                Toast.makeText(CardActivity.this, "Clicked!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте после свайпа, там же где Тост, добавить

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Пробовал, не помогло

Comment: Мне кажется, что значит, вам нужно избавиться от массива, потому что он не может удалять элементы и использовать ArrayList, так же, как в образце

Comment: Да, так все получилось! Спасибо)